# App Crashed when device time is in 24 hour format

Tags: swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

In my App if IPhone device time is in 12 hour formate then date formatter works correctly but if device time is in 24 hour formate then app crashed.

```
 let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter();
 dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
 dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.NoStyle;
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a";
 var dt1 = dateFormatter.dateFromString(arrSecond.objectAtIndex(n) as! String)
```

Comment: let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()                     dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.NoStyle
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"                                                   var dt1 = dateFormatter.dateFromString(arrSecond.objectAtIndex(n) as! String)

Comment: arrSecond.objectAtIndex(n) as! String = 07:45 AM

Comment: paste your code in post instead of comments.

Comment: let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
       var dt1 = dateFormatter.dateFromString(“07:45 AM”)
let newDate1:NSDate = dt1!.dateByAddingTimeInterval(NSTimeInterval((durationStatus * 60)))
        let str5 = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(newDate1)
 self.picker1.reloadAllComponents()

Comment: This is my code. When my device time is 12 hours formate it works correctly but when device time is in 24 hours formate app crashed beacause var dt1 is nil.

Comment: @nandini This is indeed a nice question because none of the answers on StackOverflow handles date with the date format according to phone settings. Check my answer. Working Fine.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

@Rajan Thanks for giving me idea of `NSLocale`. I set the dateformatter's locale identifier to "`en_US_POSIX`".
i just add this below line in my code after allocating date formatter.  `dateformatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier:"en_US_POSIX")`
 Thanks frnd for giving this idea

Comment: Do I loose localization support if I specifically hardcode to "en_US_POSIX"?

Comment: Your date will be displayed in english. try this : 
dateformatter.locale = Locale(identifier: NSLocale.current.identifier)

Answer (score 6):

Nandini answer is correct. But the only issue is that if you harcode the locale, the dates are displayed only in english.

In my case I wanted it in french, here is a workaround that worked for me in **Swift 3** :

```
dateformatter.locale = Locale(identifier: NSLocale.current.identifier)
```

Comment: Isn't it the same as `Locale.current`?

Comment: I tried with Locale.current but it is still crashing for me .. Is it working for you ?

Comment: Of course. No idea why you can't use Locale.current, I use it in my apps without any issue.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are using Swift 2.x version after seeing your code.

The problem is because your `dateFormatter` contains `a` and for the 24 Hour Format time we don't have `a`

So in order to fix your problem, you have to check whether your device is in 24-Hour format or 12 Hour format

Taking your array's index object in a variable `time` and keep that as `var` because we will change that later.

```
var time = arrSecond.objectAtIndex(n) as! String //this contains 07:45 AM

//Now create your Date Formatter
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter();
dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.NoStyle;

//Now check whether your phone is in 12 hour or 24 hour format 
let locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
let formatter : String = NSDateFormatter.dateFormatFromTemplate("j", options:0, locale:locale)!

//we have to change our dateFormatter as per the hour format
if formatter.containsString("a") {
    print("phone is in 12 Hour Format")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a";
} else {
    print("phone is in 24 Hour Format")
    time = convertTo24HourFormat(time) //time changed to 24 Hour format and AM/PM removed from string
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm";
}

let finalDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(time)
print(finalDate!)
```

And we need a function to make your time string converted to 24 hour format if your phone is in 24 Hour Format.
Function defination of `convertTo24HourFormat` is

```
//Example 08:45 PM to 20:45
func convertTo24HourFormat(time:String) -> String {
    var formattedTime = time
    if formattedTime.containsString("PM") {
        var hour = Int(formattedTime.substringToIndex(formattedTime.startIndex.advancedBy(2)))
        if hour != 12 {
            hour = hour! + 12
            formattedTime.removeRange(Range<String.Index>(start: formattedTime.startIndex, end: formattedTime.startIndex.advancedBy(2)))
            formattedTime = "\(hour!)\(formattedTime)"
        }

    } else {
        // For AM time
        var hour = Int(formattedTime.substringToIndex(formattedTime.startIndex.advancedBy(2)))

        //case for 12 AM
        if hour == 12 {
            formattedTime.removeRange(Range<String.Index>(start: formattedTime.startIndex, end: formattedTime.startIndex.advancedBy(2)))
            formattedTime = "00\(formattedTime)"
        }
    }
    formattedTime = formattedTime.substringToIndex(time.startIndex.advancedBy(5))

    return formattedTime
}
```

But converting only the time to date object don't make any sense as it will give a wrong date.

**NOTE:-**
The `convertTo24HourFormat` function will only work fine if you send the time in the format `hh:mm a`. For example **07:45 AM**

Answer (score 2):

I had to change my formatter from this:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MM yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS"
```

to this:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MM yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS"
```

Comment: but if the user changes the clock to 12 hrs then again it will crash.

Comment: if the clock of the phone is set to 12 hrs then this will return the null date object